# Do we have a discrete Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Hilbert space and Discrete space are well studied. But many problems appear to be workable in both domain.

> So do we have a discrete Hilbert space? I mean a usual Hilbert space but from a discrete sets.

While thinking about it, I got the following link:

http://dabacon.org/pontiff/?p=1262

But still looking to grasp the idea.

Comment: "Hilbert space from a discrete sets"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Well, $\{0\}$ seems to be Hilbert and discrete. ;-)

Comment: $\ell^2\left(\mathbb{N}\right):=\{\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mid\sum|x_n|^2<+\infty\}$ is an example.